# Poincare inequality with small modification

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $f:B^n_1 \to \Bbb{R}$ defined on the n dimensional ball of radiu $1$. If $f\in C^1$. and $f(0) = 0$.

Can we prove that $$\int_{B_1}|f|^2 \le C\int_{B_1}|\nabla f|^2 +C'$$

If assume further that $m(\{x:|f(x)|\le 1\})\ge \delta |B_1|$ for some constant $\delta >0$ which independent on the choice of $f$.

Can we prove $$\int_{B_1}|f|^2 \le C\int_{B_1}|\nabla f|^2 + C'$$ then?

Comment: The two inequalities are the same? Also this is not really a 'Sobolev inequality' but a 'Poincaré inequality'

Comment: @Calvin Khor  , no they are not the same? in the second one we consider the problem in the smaller class that $m(\{x:|f(x)|\le 1\})\ge \delta |B_1|
$ with $\delta$ independent choice of $f$

Comment: Yes, but I just wanted to confirm if the **inequalities** are the same, or you wanted to type something different. An inequality is something like "A≤B", not asking about the assumptions

Comment: If there is no mistake, then it sounds like they want you to think the first one has a counterexample. I don't know / have time to look into it atm....good luck. Though you can perhaps try the proof of Poincare in Evans for the second part

Comment: This is not true if $n>1$. If it would be true, then it would be true for all $H^1(B^n_1)$ functions, which it is clearly not.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you this is a nice point for $n = 1$ every function in $H^1$ has continuous representation, while $n \ge 2$ the continuous representation needs not to exist ,therefore to force $f =0$ at point is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I should made the statement more formal, for the second version,we have :

**Theorem.** For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $ C=C(\varepsilon, n)$ such that for $u \in H^{1}\left(B_{1}\right)$ with
$$
\left|\left\{x \in B_{1} ; u=0\right\}\right| \geq \varepsilon\left|B_{1}\right| \quad \text { there holds } \int_{B_{1}} u^{2} \leq C \int_{B_{1}}|D u|^{2}
$$

The proof is similar to the proof for the poincare wirtinger inequality on Evan's PDE book. This proof can also be found on Q. Han and F. Lin, Elliptic partial differential equations. 4.8.

With slight modification, we can prove the following result :

**Theorem** For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $ C=C(\varepsilon, n)$ such that for $u \in H^{1}\left(B_{1}\right)$ with
$$
\left|\left\{x \in B_{1} ; |u|<\frac{1}{2}\right\}\right| \geq \varepsilon\left|B_{1}\right| \quad \text { there holds } \int_{B_{1}} u^{2} \leq C \int_{B_{1}}|D u|^{2}
$$

**Proof.** Suppose not. Then there exists a sequence $\left\{u_{m}\right\} \subset H^{1}\left(B_{1}\right)$ such that $\left|\left\{x \in B_{1} ; |u_{m}|<\frac{1}{2}\right\}\right| \geq \varepsilon\left|B_{1}\right|, \quad \int_{B_{1}} u_{m}^{2}=1, \quad \int_{B_{1}}\left|D u_{m}\right|^{2} \rightarrow 0$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$
Hence we may assume $u_{m} \rightarrow u_{0} \in H^{1}\left(B_{1}\right)$ strongly in $L^{2}\left(B_{1}\right)$ and weakly in $H^{1}\left(B_{1}\right)$(Using the Sobolev embedding). Clearly $u_{0}$ is a nonzero constant,and $|u_0| > \frac{1}{2}$

which is constant since $Du =0$ by the fact that $Du_m \to 0$ in $L^2$ , it's non-zero since $\|u_m\| = 1 $ so the limit in $L^2$ can not have zero $L^2$ norm. since $\|u_0\|_{L^2(B_1)} =1$, therefore $|u_0|> \frac{1}{2}$ .

So:

$$
\begin{aligned}
0=\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \int_{B_{1}}\left|u_{m}-u_{0}\right|^{2} & \geq \lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\left\{|u_{m}|<\frac{1}{2}\right\}}\left|u_{m}-u_{0}\right|^{2} \\
& \geq (|u_0| - \frac{1}{2})^2 \inf_m|\{x:|u_m|<\frac{1}{2}\}| >0
\end{aligned}
$$
Contradiction.

Comment: The condition with $\epsilon$ on $u_m$ is wrong (its taken from first theorem).

Comment: the proof needs $u_0>1/2$, $u_0 \ne 1/2$ is not enough.

Comment: thank you I have modified it.

Comment: Oh I found a problem , $\left|\left\{x \in B_{1} ; |u_{m}|<\frac{1}{2}\right\}\right| \geq \varepsilon\left|B_{1}\right|,$ is not preserved under the normalization while $\left|\left\{x \in B_{1} ; u=0\right\}\right| \geq \varepsilon\left|B_{1}\right| \quad $ is ok, that's why we choose this condition.